# (Angular 2+) Trying to set a sessionStorage-based var ngOnInit() but undefined after page loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, angular5

I have a Angular 2+ Project, and i'm trying to set my userAuth var to use localStorage value.
It sets okay but when it pass through ngOnInit() it returns undefined. So... that's the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.authGuardService.userLogado.subscribe(
    retorno => {
      this.userAuth = retorno;
    }
  );
  this.userAuth = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('Login_Infos'));
}
```

When i tried to debug this execution, i noticed that when i'm inside onInit, my "this.userAuth" has his value, but when i continue inside the execution, my var gets undefined again.

Service that's setting 'Login_Infos' item.

```
  AutenticarLogin(user: string, password: string) {
    const retorno = this.RetornoMBS.filter (tabledata => {
      if (user === tabledata.user && password === tabledata.password) {
        this.userAuth.logado = true;
        this.userAuth.user = user;
        this.userAuth.permissoes = tabledata.permissoes;
        sessionStorage.setItem('Login_Infos', JSON.stringify(this.userAuth));
        this.route.navigate(['/']);
        return true;
      } else {
        this.invalidLogin = true;
      }
    });
```

Please, someone could help me?

Comment: You mentioned local storage but you are trying to get the value from session storage. could that be the problem ?

Comment: and you are assigning the userauth value again in subscribe method..can you debug that if observable is not returning undefined

Comment: @DrNio, no, it's just my mistake, i'm sorry... It's session Storage that i'm using.

Comment: @KaranGarg, i tried to comment those lines of code that was using the subscribe method to test it, but when i pass on this.userAuth = JSON.parse..... and click on "Step over next function call" this.userAuth loses its value.

Comment: Are there other lines of code in this component where you change the content of `userAuth`? If it is possible, please add your entire ts-file and the code that initially sets the 'Login_Infos'-item to the session storage.

Comment: @DiabolicWords, no it's not changed on my .ts file, i've added the service that sets 'Login_infos' item. Take a look at this

Comment: This looks valid to me. Is there any piece of code inside the component (where your ngOnInit() is located) that could possibly reset uerAuth?

Comment: @DiabolicWords, no, it hadn't